# Using environment variable inside a library

Tags: python, environment-variables, pydantic

I am currently using a private repo as a library. I am able to install it as a library and was able to import and call to the functions inside it. However, the repo uses a separate settings file like this:

```py
    from pydantic import BaseSettings
    class Settings(BaseSettings):
        DW_USER: str = os.getenv("DW_USER")
        DW_PASSWORD: str = os.getenv("DW_PASSWORD")
        DW_HOST: str = os.getenv("DW_HOST")
        DW_PORT: str = "5432"
        DW_DATABASE: str = os.getenv("DW_DATABASE")

        class Config:
           case_sensitive = False

       @validator("sqlalchemy_database_uri", pre=True)
       # pylint: disable=no-self-argument
       def assemble_db_connection(cls, v: Optional[str], values: Dict[str, Any]) -> Any:
       
           if isinstance(v, str):
               return v
           return PostgresDsn.build(
               scheme="postgresql+psycopg2",
               user=values.get("DW_USER"),
               password=values.get("DW_PASSWORD"),
               host=values.get("DW_HOST"),
               port=values.get("DW_PORT"),
               path=f"/{values.get('DW_DATABASE') or ''}",
           )
```

and even though my .env file already has these variables and the main project is able to access these, this particular settings class can't. They are all None. This file is located inside the repo, so it is inside the library code. Currently most of the code of the repo import this settings to run so refractoring will be a lot of work.

Is it possible for me to use variables from .env file inside of this class as is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you class `Settings` needs a `class Config:` member. see: https://lynn-kwong.medium.com/how-to-use-pydantic-to-read-environment-variables-and-secret-files-in-python-8a6b8c56381c

Comment: It does have a config already. I have updated the question with the full class.

Comment: is there another library that loads the values from the .env file into the shell env? (e.g. such as https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) I am wondering if perhaps your pydantic model above is getting imported before the dotenv code has run

Comment: Yes I use dotenv to load the env file. However in my library I have this in the init file of the library/repo as well: 



```
   from dotenv import load_dotenv
   load_dotenv()
```



Also please note that the library is working fine as an independent repo.

Comment: The issue could be that the settings class is searching for the .env file inside the library path and not in your project. I also came across this and looking for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing out your class a bit so as to specify the `env_file`

```py
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    DW_USER: str = os.getenv("DW_USER")
    DW_PASSWORD: str = os.getenv("DW_PASSWORD")
    DW_HOST: str = os.getenv("DW_HOST")
    DW_PORT: str = "5432"
    DW_DATABASE: str = os.getenv("DW_DATABASE")

    class Config:
        env_prefix = ""
        case_sentive = False
        env_file = '.env'
        env_file_encoding = 'utf-8'
```